# I want to split a list into a tupple of odd and even elements

Tags: sml

Hi all im new to programming and im doing a problem for learning and enjoyment. Im a bit stuck at this point.. The problem is from `Introduction to Programming using Sml 5.9`

I want to split a list of `[x1, x2, x3, ... ,xn] = ([x1, x3,....], [x2, x4,...])`

This is what I have made so far:

```
fun split [] =  []
  | split (x1::x2::x3::x4::xs) = ([x1, x3], [x2, x4])::split xs



val test1split = split [1, 1, 2, 3];
```

From this I get:

`[([1, 2], [1, 3])]`.... (I want a tuple with splitting list and not this obviously)

If there are more than 4 elements then the function doesn't work. Maybe I need a helper function to sort even and odd elements in a list first? I hope someone can help me with tracking my mind in the correct direction, until then I keep trying.

Comment: Welcome! To make your question and code more readable, try using some formatting in your post. Code can be formatted by putting 4 space characters before each line (or by highlighting it all and pressing the 'code' button on the edit bar).

Comment: Thx alot for the highlighting tip

Comment: I've never used the language before but if you can split based on the array index you could use something like (index mod 2) or indexA - (indexA >> 1) == indexA - 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try not to give too much away, but here are some tips:

- You need two base cases - one for `[]`, one for `[x]`.
- Your general case only needs to deal with two elements, not four (putting one in the first list, and one in the second)
- At the moment, you've got `split` returning a list, rather than a tuple. The result of your first base case should be `([],[])`.
- In the general case, the recursive `split xs` will return a tuple `(ys,zs)`. You need to extract these values, and build the resulting tuple in terms of `ys`, `zs`, `x1` and `x2`.

**(Edit)** A couple of points on your revised solution:

- You only need to deal with two elements at a time - the general case should be `split x1::x2::xs`
- `split [x,y]` is handled by the general case - no need for another base case.
- You're missing the recursive call! Elements are ending up in both lists because you're putting `xs` directly into both halves of your output - you need to split it first. Start with
  `let (ys, zs) = split xs in ...`

Comment: Thx 100 times.. That clears things up a bit. Im going to sleep 4 am, will post the solution tommorow. Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

```
fun split [] = ([], [])   
  | split [x] = ([x], [])  
  | split (x1::x2::xs) = 
               let 
                 val (ys, zs) = split xs
               in 
                ((x1::ys), (x2::zs))
              end;



val test1split = split [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6] = ([1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 6])
val test2split = split [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3] = ([8, 6, 4], [7, 5, 3])
val test3split = split [8, 7] = ([8], [7])
val test4split = split [8] = ([8], [])
```

Solved it... Not completely sure how lol, need alot more practice to master it. Couldn't have done it without the pointers... Thx alot for the help Nick Barnes.